# issues/errors with from php form for sending email via local host Xampp using php-mailer library

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

I am trying to fill in a php form i have on my website and send the content of the form to my email when the form is submitted. i am using Xampp local host . so within the "htdocs" folder i have my "website" folder as well as the "phpmailer" folder which i downloaded from GitHub.

On local host when i fill in  the form , i get a warning and an error message as shown below:

Warning: require(phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/websiteproject/booking.php on line 5

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/websiteproject/booking.php on line 5

Even when i put the phpmailer folder inside of the website folder it doesn't work. i would appreciate any help to make this work.  many thanks

this is my code :

```html
<?php 

$result="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 
 $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
 $smail->port=587;
 $smail->SMTPAuth=true;
 $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
 $mail->Username='myemail@gmail.com';
 $mail->Password= 'mypassword';
 
 $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
 $mail->addAddress('myemail');
 $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
 
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Body= '<h1 align=center> Name :' .$_POST['name'].'<br> Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br> 
 Contact: '.$_POST['contactnumber'].'<br> Date: '.$_POST['date'].'<br> Services: '.$_POST['service'].'<br>
 Stylist: '.$_POST['stylist'].'</h1>';
 
 
 if(!$mail->send()){
  echo "Something went wrong, Please try again.";
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
           echo "Thanks".$_POST['name']." for your booking";
 } 
}

?>



<!doctype html>

<html lang="en"><head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <title>Clypsdra Barber</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
 <!-- awesome-font CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>
<body>


 <div class="bookingform">
    <h5 "class=text-center text-success"> <?=$result; ?></h5>
    <form class="testform" action="" method="post" >   
 <h1>Make your booking</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Your Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="full name">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email address</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="your e-mail">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="contactnumber">Contact Number</label>
       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contactnumber" placeholder="Mobile number">
    </div>
 
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="date">Book your date</label>
       <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
 
  <div class="serv">
   <p>Select services:</p>
  <select name="services">
   <option value="s"> Please Select</option>
   <option value="hc">Haircut --- £13</option>
   <option value="cw">Wash &#43; Cut £20 Clipper cut</option>
   <option value="su">Shape Up --- £7</option>
   <option value="bt">Beard trim --- £8</option>
      <option value="cb">Cut + Beard ---  £23 </option>
   <option value="cc">Clipper Cut --- £10</option>
   <option value="hts">Hot Towel Shave --- £12</option>
  </select>
  </div>
      
     
     <div class="styl">
   <p>Choose Stylist:</p>
  <select name="stylist">
   <option value="Kocher">Kocher</option>
   <option value="Dyako">Dyako</option>
   <option value="Omeed">Omeed</option>
      <option value="Omeed">Burhan</option>
  </select>
  </div>
 
     <div class="formsubmit">
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   </div>
   </form>
 </div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
   <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $('.first-button').on('click', function () {

    $('.animated-icon1').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
   
   </script>
  
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you downloaded the [latest PHPMailer from github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), it won't work with that old code, because the file you're trying to load no longer exists. Base your code on [the gmail example code provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps). Read the readme and other docs if you get into trouble.

Comment: i downloaded  the 5.2 stable version. and when i tested with index.php file  following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLuPFzHQ8Xo&t=6s  i managed to send email successfully to myself . but i wasn't able to implement it for the form that i have on my website. not sure why.

Comment: You should not be using that old version for any new development, especially when you have full control over your runtime environment in XAMPP. The error you're seeing simply means you've got your path to the file wrong, either because you're using the wrong relative path, because you have not set the correct search locations in your php.ini `include_path` directive, or because your current working directory is not where you think it is. Try prepending `__DIR__` to your relative path.

Comment: I am newbie to web development , i am not sure how to change the path , unfortunately.  but both my "website" folder and "phpmailer" folder are inside the htdocs of the Xampp folder, even when i moved the phpmailer inside the website folder , it still did not work. so i am not sure what to do : (  btw  is there any youtube videos for the other phpmailer example you provided?

Comment: No other videos I know of - others may have made them though. If your phpmailer folder is in the same place as this script, try changing your require command to: `require __DIR__ . '/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`; this will make it ignore your current working directory.

Comment: I have my phpmailer and website folder inside htdocs folder. sorry for being dumb and slow,  i changed  require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';  **to**  require __ DIR __ 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';   , but i still get the same error when i fill and submit the form.   is there anywhere i can show you my whole folder so you can check it pls.

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere! That sounds like your phpmailer folder is *not* in the same place as your script. Perhaps try adding `/../` to the phpmailer path to lead it to the right folder.

Comment: Omg i think i fixed it,  i moved the phpmailer folder inside of the website folder where i have my booking.php script  ,  and when i filled in the form  , i get  the echo :   **  echo "Thanks".$_POST['name']." for your booking";  ** , but i did not get any email ?  why do you think is that ? what do i need to do to fix this pls help.

Comment: Read the troubleshooting guide, and look up how to debug PHP - it’s too much to answerable in one Q!

Comment: omg what a magic :D my code was missing  **$mail->isSMTP();**  i added it and i get all the emails now :D  i am sending tons of email to myself in celebration .  i would like to thank you for  all your help :) its well appreciated

Comment: Many thanks , i am really new to this whole new web development , especially php.  i have spent few days to fix these issues. but finally i manage to fix it.    just one last question . if i add a new page **contact.php** to my website and have a contact form in it. do i just use the same php code  i have and tweak it to send email from it ?

Comment: Yes. Later you might like to learn about composer, testing, and frameworks to help you structure things better.